# Construct a sequence having two alternate properties of a class as elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like this:

```
class Person
{
    string Name;
    string Job;
}
```

And I have a list of `Person`:

```
List<Person> persons;
```

Now I would like to write a function to construct a sequence based on `persons`, and having as elements the alternate values of `Name` and `Job`. For example, if I had:

```
persons.Add(new Person("Alice", "Accountant"));
persons.Add(new Person("Bob", "Butler"));
persons.Add(new Person("Chris", "Cleaner"));
```

Then the result of my function would be a sequence of strings like this:

```
"Alice", "Accountant", "Bob", "Butler", "Chris", "Cleaner"
```

Of course, I can do this by using a loop, but I'd like to find a way to do it in a single LINQ line, if possible.

Comment: persons.SelectMany(p => new[]{p.Name,p.Job});

Comment: Wow, is it that easy? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
persons.SelectMany(p => new[] { p.Name, p.Job });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:
Override `ToString` in the `Person` class like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Name + "," + Job;
}
```

Then if you want to have the result as a `List` of `String`:

```
List<string> result = persons.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Or use `SelectMany` to flatten your list:

```
List<string> result2 = persons.SelectMany(p => new[] {p.Name, p.Job}).ToList();
```